# What is the difference between scheduling same task using alarm manager vs ScheduledExecutorService

Tags: android, alarmmanager, scheduledexecutorservice

Hi I was reading on internet that we can schedule any thing which we want to run at a gap of certain interval using alarm manager and `ScheduledExecutorService`.

I want to know what is the difference between them and what to use when

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`ScheduledExecutorService` is something *inside* your process. If your process is already around for other reasons, such as it is supplying the foreground UI, and you want to use `ScheduledExecutorService` for periodic work, that's fine. However, once your app moves to the background, its process may go away at any time, taking your `ScheduledExecutorService` with it, and you will no longer get control periodically.

`AlarmManager` is something *outside* your process. If you are looking for the Android equivalent of Windows' "Scheduled Tasks", or OS X/Linux **`cron`** jobs, that is what `AlarmManager` (or `JobScheduler` on Android 5.0+) is for. These are for cases where you need application code to run periodically in the background but are happy to allow your process to possibly be terminated in between those periods.

Comment: Nice answer :) +1, I can accept this nice answer in 8 mins.